# Animation between Elevated and Outlined button

Tags: flutter, dart, button, flutter-animation

I want a button to change between `ElevatedButton` and `OutlinedButton`. I have this code snipped:

```dart
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  var _highlighted = false;

  void _onPressed() {
    setState(() {
      _highlighted = !_highlighted;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const buttonContent = Text('Button');
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: _highlighted
            ? ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _onPressed,
                child: buttonContent,
              )
            : OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: _onPressed,
                child: buttonContent,
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

I would like the transition to be "smooth". When the button changes from one style to another, it would like it to be animated. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get the desired effect using `AnimatedTheme`.

Look at the widget `AnimatedButton` in the following code snippet:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
          style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
            foregroundColor: Colors.white,
            side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          ),
        ),
        elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            foregroundColor: Colors.black,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      home: const Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  var _highlighted = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: AnimatedButton(
          highlighted: _highlighted,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _highlighted = !_highlighted;
            });
          },
          child: const Text('Button'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnimatedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const AnimatedButton({
    required this.child,
    required this.highlighted,
    required this.onPressed,
    super.key,
  });

  final Widget child;
  final bool highlighted;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    return AnimatedTheme(
      data: theme.copyWith(
        outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
          style: highlighted
              ? theme.elevatedButtonTheme.style
              : theme.outlinedButtonTheme.style,
        ),
      ),
      child: OutlinedButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The result is (with "slow animation" enabled):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply use AnimatedSwitcher widget

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
  child: _highlighted
      ? ElevatedButton(
          key: ValueKey("elevated"),
          onPressed: _onPressed,
          child: buttonContent,
        )
      : OutlinedButton(
          key: ValueKey("outlined"),
          onPressed: _onPressed,
          child: buttonContent,
        ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, while `AnimatedSwitcher` does introduce an animation, it is not the one I want. I want one button to "transform itself"/ "morph" into the other one